# Create subset Dask dataframe based on another Dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have two Dask dataframes, df1 of length 5000 and df2 of length 100000, both with start_time and end_time columns. I am **trying to find the df1 rows where df2's start_time-end_time interval is smaller or equal with df1's start_time-end_time interval** (df1.start_time <= df2.start_time <= df2.end_time <= df2.end_time).

I have tried the following, but to no avail:

```py
df3 = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(), npartitions=1)
for _, df2_row in df2.iterrows():
    df3_chunk = df1.apply(lambda df1_row: df1_row.start_time <= df2_row.start_time <= df2_row.end_time <= df1_row.end_time, axis=1)
    df3 = dd.concat([df3, df3_chunk])
```

```py
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
for _, df2_row in df2.iterrows():
    df3_chunk = df1.loc[df1.start_time <= df2_row.start_time <= df2_row.end_time <= df1.end_time]
    df3 = dd.concat([df3, df3_chunk])
```

The first snippet has been running for forever, whilst the second returns `` ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use `set_index` to set the index. ``

Example inputs (df1, df2) and output (df3):

```
# df1
start_time, end_time
2019-10-10 01:01:01, 2019-10-11 01:01:01
2001-01-01 00:00:01, 2001-02-02 03:04:05

# df2
start_time, end_time
2019-10-10 09:07:05, 2019-10-10 11:12:10

# df3
start_time, end_time
2019-10-10 01:01:01, 2019-10-11 01:01:01
```

Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please provide an example of your dataframe an your expected output

Comment: Thank you. I've edited the question with example inputs and output :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from necessary import:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
```

For the test purpose, I read the source (*Pandas*) DataFrames (*df1* and *df2*)
and then converted them to *Dask* DataFrames:

```
dd1 = dd.from_pandas(df1, npartitions=2)
dd2 = dd.from_pandas(df2, npartitions=2)
```

In your program (as I suppose) you will read them directly from
respective input files.

Then define the following function:

```
def enclosesAny(row, other):
    return (other.start_time.ge(row.start_time) &
        other.end_time.le(row.end_time)).any()
```

And the actual computation is divided into 2 steps:

1. Compute *encl* column - the result of application of the above function
   to each row:

   ```
   dd1['encl'] = dd1.map_partitions(enclosesAny, other=dd2)
   ```
2. Generate the actual result. It contains rows from *dd1* for which
   *encl* is *True*. In order not to clutter the result with additional
   columns, I dropped *encl* column:

   ```
   result = dd1[dd1.encl].drop('encl', axis=1).compute()
   ```